# Construct a 2 generator group $G$ that is an extension of a free abelian group $N$ of infinite rank by an infinite cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Construct a 2 generator group $G$ that is an extension of a free abelian group $N$ of infinite rank by an infinite cyclic group

I'm looking for a quick example of this, I've been trying to figure this out for awhile and can't get anywhere! An answer with an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** A group generated by $2$ elements is a quotient of the free group $F_2$ on $2$ generators.

Comment: Just take the wreath product of two infinite cyclic groups.

Comment: @Berci But I need $N$ to be a group of infinite rank, and $F_2$ has rank 2. Right?

Comment: Yes. However, $F_2$ contains $F_\omega$ as a subgroup..

Comment: Ah man, I'm still confused, sorry. So I start with $F_\omega$, mode out by an infinite cyclic group, and end up with a 2-generator group? I don't see how that's possible.